# Sockets.io | Undefined number

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

Here is my app.js file (express, socket.io):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var serv = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
});

app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

serv.listen(2000);
console.log('Server has started.');

var socket_list = {};

var io = require('socket.io')(serv, {});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.id = Math.random();
    socket.x = 0;
    socket.y = 0;
    socket.number = "" + Math.floor(10 * Math.random());
    socket_list[socket.id] = socket;

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        delete socket_list[socket.id];
    });
});

setInterval(function() {
    var pack = [];
    for(var i in socket_list) {
        var socket = socket_list[i];
        socket.x++;
        socket.y++;
        pack.push({
            x: socket.x,
            y: socket.y,
            number: socket.number
        })
    };

    for(var i in socket_list) {
        var socket = socket_list[i];
        socket.emit('newPositions', pack);
    };
}, 25);socket.on('connect', function() { connectCounter++; });
```

and this is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiplayer | HTML5</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="ctx" width="512" height="512" style="border: 1px solid #000;"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
            ctx.font = '24px Calibri';

            var socket = io();

            socket.on('newPositions', function(data) {
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,512,512);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    ctx.fillText(data[i].number, data[i].x, data[i].y);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The end result is supposed to have it so that a random number is generated, the number is then displayed on canvas and slowly moves towards the bottom right of the screen.

If another player were join from another device (or just a new tab) then it'd have the first player's randomly generated number, as well as second player's number. Both most likely to be different numbers.

An example of this happening is at the end of this video: 8:23 - https://youtu.be/_GioD4LpjMw?t=503

For some unknown reason the number that should be displayed in the canvas is "undefined".

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I could not reproduce the error in your post. However, it looks like you've improperly closed your html tags in your client code. Try changing your client code to this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Multiplayer | HTML5</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="ctx" width="512" height="512" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
            ctx.font = '24px Calibri';

            var socket = io();

            socket.on('newPositions', function(data) {
                ctx.clearRect(0,0,512,512);
                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                    ctx.fillText(data[i].number, data[i].x, data[i].y);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What changed? (BTW, Welcome to Stack Overflow).

Comment: If you're talking about the `<script />` and `<canvas />` some guy just edited my question to change those two tags to do that. My original code is just like yours. I'd also like to mention that I don't think <script />  and <script> </script> makes a difference (same with canvas).

Comment: Yea, I think you're actually correct. I've reproduced the code exactly as stated and it's working fine for me. Can you try logging out the value of `data` and check to see if `number` is undefined there (on the client side)?

Comment: It seems the problem is with the server side or the connection from the server side to client side.

Comment: I think the problem may just be with me... I copied and pasted code from the original author and the client.html won't even show up...

Comment: Everyone was working fine... and I haven't really done anything but follow the tutorial

Comment: Note to me: Since `<script>` typically contains some JavaScript code that needs to be executed. It requires a closing tag to indicate where the potential code ends. On the other hand, `<img>`, and `<input>` can use the self-closing tag because they don't need to have anything in between the opening and closing tags because all the data they need to function is found in the tags' attributes.